# Android TextView and 9 Patch Not laying out Correctly

Tags: android, background, textview, nine-patch

I have a vertical linear layout and I want to add a background the text view.  I am using 9 patch which I've done for buttons no problem.  My 9 patch graphic is correct but this is what get when its displayed in the layout. The numbers are supposed to be evenly spaced.  If I don't put the 9 patch there the layout displays fine (one field gets pushed out of view).  What is going on here? I don't want to hard code the height of the textview, hence why I am using a 9Patch.

[image: Bad 9 Patch!]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_DisplayGraph"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_DisplayFeatures"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" 
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_graphtab"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" 
            android:longClickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@color/orange1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--More layouts here but cut short for brevity ->

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: 9Patch image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial 9-patch size is larger than the minimum size that you want your buttons to be.

[image: Example]

Try something like the attached; reduce it to the smallest possible size without eliminating information that you need.

Comment: Hmm didn't think that 9 patch had to be smaller than the size of the layout, I thought it grew or shrank accordingly

Comment: You can force it to shrink (if you specify a dimension) but it will introduce artifacts. Each "patch" of the image is a bitmap, so by definition it has to be at *least* as large as the initial image to avoid any artifacting.